# Track clicks ads keep refreshing my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp, buttonclick

I am trying to track clicks on a button.

I don´t know why the webpage keeps refreshing all of the time when I click the button.

The JavaScript function is:

```
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
          //window.location = url;
      }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-794835902/fpj1CObz6YgBEL73gPsC',
      'transaction_id': '',
      'event_callback': callback
  });

  return false;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<button id="agendar-button" 
  type="button" 
  class="btn-agendar btn-lg btn btn-green btn-radius uppercase omnes-medium" 
  uid="<?= $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id') ?>" 
  rel='<?= \Cake\Routing\Router::url(['prefix' => false, 'controller' => 'Agendamentos', 'action' => 'addAgendamento']) ?>' 
  onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('<?= \Cake\Routing\Router::url($this->request->here, true); ?>')">
  Agendar
</button>
```

Comment: Have you debug your code? any error message before page load in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `<button>` is implemented within a `<form>` tag. Clicking on the button may cause the form content to be sent. So check if there is a formular and if so, you have a simple trick how to prevent the formular from being submitted. A last possibility could also be that your browser unintentionally adds such a form.

```
document.getElementById('agendar-button').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

While tracking the fired events onto your `<button>` with the ID `agendar-button` you will prevent the browser from emitting the default behaviour. In your case the reload of the webpage.